# Create a Popover view from UIButton which shows a TableView with the list on inApp purchase items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a popover and it is showing me my in app purchase items list. I have implemente classes used by Ray Wenderlich tutorials. But something is definitely wrong. My problems are:

1. Popover is being shown with Max height. (I don't want it to be shown with MAX height of iPad)
2. If i close popover by clicking some where else, and again click the button to show popover, It opens popover but doesn't load the view in it.

Please help guys I'm in real confusion/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am displaying popOverViewController from SearchDelivery.xib that contains tableView & Search bar in it. In other .xib file I am showing popover on button click code is below that can help you .

```
-(IBAction)deliveryList:(UIButton*)sender
{
SearchDelivery *searchDel1=[[SearchDelivery alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchDelivery" bundle:nil];

[searchDel1 loadDelAdd:self.arr];
self.searchDel=searchDel1;
[searchDel1 release];

UIPopoverController *popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:searchDel];
popover.delegate=self;

CGRect rect=searchDel.view.frame;
popover.popoverContentSize=rect.size;

self.popOverController=popover;
[popover release];

[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];

}
```

**popoverContentSize Property is used to set width and height of popOverView.**

Comment: If your view is not loading in popOver please post your code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below given code

```
    -(IBAction)setData1:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *popoverContent=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *tableView1=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 680, 0, 0)   style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UIView *popoverView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 300)];

    popoverView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    popoverContent.view=popoverView;
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(200, 420);
    popoverContent.view=tableView1;   //Use this if you like to add a tableView in popover
    tableView1.delegate=self;
    tableView1.dataSource=self;

    self.popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, 675, 1000, 1000) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

}